# Ubuntu 20.04 Slow on Acer Aspire TimeLineX 4830T

Tags: 20.04

I'm a new user. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Laptop Acer Aspire TimelineX,

My laptop's specifications are:

```
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit
Intel® Core™ i3-2370M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
Intel® HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2)
4 GB RAM
```

[image]

Comment: What is running slow and when?

Comment: well, when i open "Show Applications" gets slow or when i start my laptop and "log in" for example....but it's a very common kind of lag, plus when I open certain applications like "Krita" or "Rhythmbox" it takes about 30 seconds or 40 seconds to open.

Comment: I think it might be a lack of ram memory, or a lack of processor.

Comment: Slow starting of applications is because of a slow HDD. If you have many applicatins open, especially browser tabs, the system starts swapping. You can try to install `zram-config`. It must improve RAM usage a bit. 4 GB is just enough for modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

What io scheduler is being used on your system?
For rotational media (classic HDD) BFQ is by far the best if you want a responsive system.
Find out by using this command in a terminal:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

This will show between brackets the scheduler that is currently in use and the available schedulers on your system.
If BFQ is not on the list, you will need to enable it (it is a kernel module) with modprobe:

```
sudo modprobe bfq
```

If BFQ is on the list but not selected, or you just used modprobe to install it, you can enable it as follows:

```
echo "bfq" | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

Check if it is being used by issuing the same cat command as we started with, it should now show BFQ in between brackets.

With BFQ as your scheduler, now try to use the same applications that took so long to open, if it is faster you can make the scheduler change permanent by creating an UDEV rule.
Go to or create (if it does not exist) the following directory: `/etc/udev/rules.d`
Open or create a file in that directory (as root) named 60-scheduler.rules
Insert or add the following line to that file:

```
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DRIVERS=="sd|sr", ATTR{queue/scheduler}!="bfq", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="bfq"
```

save the file, next time you reboot, your scheduler will be set to BFQ automatically